# How to print the value of the references of the objects in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Whenever I type the following on the REPL

```
(defn test_function
    []
    ()
)
```

The output is -

```
#'clojure.repl/test_function
```

As functions are objects in Clojure, how to get the value of the reference that refers to this function object?

Comment: For such basic, fundamental questions, it is better to ***read the docs*** than to ask on StackOverflow:  https://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/

Answer (score 4):

In Clojure, a Var (the Java class is clojure.lang.Var) is a container in which you can store any immutable value.  You can even store a different immutable value into this container at a later time - but, for now, let's ignore that.  The container can be referred to using a name (aka symbol). The mapping between the name and the Var is stored in each namespace.  So, when you say

```clj
(defn testf [] ())
```

that is (more or less) equivalent to

```clj
(def testf (fn [] ()))
```

That will create a Var, store the newly created function object into that Var, and create a mapping between the symbol `testf` and the Var.  You can get the function object by just evaluating the symbol.  Thus

```clj
user=> testf
#object[user$test_function 0x67207d8a "user$testf@67207d8a"]
user=> (class testf)
user$testf
```

That tells you that the function is a Java object of the class `user$testf`.

If you want to inspect the Var itself (rather than the value that it contains), you can do the following

```clj
user=> (var testf)
#'user/testf
user=> (class (var testf))
clojure.lang.Var
```

which tells you that the Var is `#'user/testf` and the Java class that implements a Clojure Var is `clojure.lang.Var`.

You might benefit from reading [Clojure - Vars and the Global Environment](https://clojure.org/reference/vars) or the sources for more details.

To finally answer your question ... you can consider the Var as the holder to a reference to the object.  In that case, you can "print" the Var that is bound to a symbol `foo` by evaluating `(var foo)`.  And you can "print" the object itself by evaluating `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure compiles your code down to JVM byte code if you load source
files and there is no way around to create classes to do that
(everything except primitive types is an Object descendant in the JVM).

You can see lot's of what is going on, if you check out an uberjar of
your lein project or if you AOT compile clj files.

You can get the `class` from your function:

```
(defn test-function []
  (println :hello))

(println (class test-function))
; ⇒ user$test_function
```

The `$` indicates, that there is an inner class used; this is just
a convention.  Also the `-` has changed to a `_`, which clojure calls
"munging".

Now you can create a new instance of that class and you can `.invoke` it
(as it's implements the
[`IFn`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/IFn.html)
interface):

```
(let [tf (new user$test_function)]
  (.invoke tf))
; ⇒ :hello
```

Comment: What the heck, why would we do any of this instead of merely writing `test_function` or `(test_function)`? I think your answer is at a level of expertise way beyond the beginner-level question.

Comment: @amalloy As long as you don't find anything technically wrong with it,
I'll stick with it. OP in it's recent questions seems very inquisitive
about how how Clojure handles things mandated by the JVM or how they
co-relate to the "OO".